# Some pictures don't show on mobile site.

Tags: discussion, bug, images, mobile-web

I've noticed that, recently, some pictures don't show on the mobile site *despite being formatted correctly.* I'm using the ZTE Blade V8.

I wonder if anyone else is experiencing this problem.

[image]

They don't work on the app either:

[image]

Both images are taken from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2811829/104041) question.

Please help :)

Comment: [I'm having the same problem on the meta site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvqk6.jpg)

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down).

Comment: [I asked this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1028119?noredirect=1) an hour ago, and directed me to a post 12 hours ago. Looks like it still hasn't be resolved.

Comment: The problem can be demonstrated by pasting an `imgur` URL directly in a browser's address bar, even using an "incognito" window.  So I strongly suspect that some (possibly inconsistent) behavior is responsible on the `imgur` side of things.

Comment: I'm now able to see the two images above, though the way I got them seems unnecessarily tedious.  I logged out of my OpenID provider and cleared cookies and cached images in Chromium (Linux, Fedora).  Then I logged back into my OpenID provider (Google) and logged back into SE.  I navigated to one of my main posts that had images, still displaying the bozo icon.  I clicked on the link to Open in a new tab, where the image appeared after a momentary glitch.  Closed that tab and refreshed my post on main, the image appears.  Repeated the process here on Meta (separately for both images).